# How can I configure the AdmissionConfiguration > PodSecurity > PodSecurityConfiguration in an EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-eks

If I understand right from [Apply Pod Security Standards at the Cluster Level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/security/cluster-level-pss/), in order to have a PSS (Pod Security Standard) as default for the whole cluster I need to create an `AdmissionConfiguration` in a file that the API server needs to consume during cluster creation.

I don't see any way to configure / provide the AdmissionConfiguration at [CreateCluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/APIReference/API_CreateCluster.html) , also I'm not sure how to provide this AdmissionConfiguration in a managed EKS node.

From the tutorials that use KinD or minikube it seems that the AdmissionConfiguration must be in a file that is referenced in the `cluster-config.yaml`, but if I'm not mistaken the EKS API server is managed and does not allow to change or even see this file.

The GitHub issue [aws/container-roadmap Allow Access to AdmissionConfiguration](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1822) seems to suggest that currently there is no possibility of providing AdmissionConfiguration at creation, but on the other hand [aws-eks-best-practices](https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/pods/#exemptions) says `These exemptions are applied statically in the PSA admission controller configuration as part of the API server configuration`

so, **is there a way to provide PodSecurityConfiguration for the whole cluster in EKS?** or I'm forced to just use per-namespace labels?

See also [Enforce Pod Security Standards by Configuration the Built-in Admission Controller](https://v1-23.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/enforce-standards-admission-controller/) and [EKS Best practices PSS and PSA](https://aws.github.io/aws-eks-best-practices/security/docs/pods/#pod-security-standards-pss-and-pod-security-admission-psa)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is any way [currently](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1822) in EKS to provide configuration for the built-in PSA controller (Pod Security Admission controller).

But if you want to implement a cluster-wide default for PSS (Pod Security Standards) you can do that by installing the the official `pod-security-webhook` as a [Dynamic Admission Controller in EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/amazon-eks-enables-support-for-kubernetes-dynamic-admission-cont/).

```
git clone https://github.com/kubernetes/pod-security-admission
cd pod-security-admission/webhook
make certs
kubectl apply -k .
```

The default `podsecurityconfiguration.yaml` in [`pod-security-admission/webhook/manifests/020-configmap.yaml`](https://github.com/kubernetes/pod-security-admission/blob/master/webhook/manifests/20-configmap.yaml) allows EVERYTHING so you should edit it and write something like

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: pod-security-webhook
  namespace: pod-security-webhook
data:
  podsecurityconfiguration.yaml: |
    apiVersion: pod-security.admission.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: PodSecurityConfiguration
    defaults:
      enforce: "restricted"
      enforce-version: "latest"
      audit: "restricted"
      audit-version: "latest"
      warn: "restricted"
      warn-version: "latest"
    exemptions:
      # Array of authenticated usernames to exempt.
      usernames: []
      # Array of runtime class names to exempt.
      runtimeClasses: []
      # Array of namespaces to exempt.
      namespaces: ["policy-test2"]
```

then

```
kubectl apply -k . 
kubectl -n pod-security-webhook rollout restart deployment/pod-security-webhook # otherwise the pods won't reread the configuration changes
```

After those changes you can verify that the default forbids privileged pods with:

```
kubectl --context aihub-eks-terraform create ns policy-test1
kubectl --context aihub-eks-terraform -n policy-test1 run --image=ecerulm/ubuntu-tools:latest --rm -ti rubelagu-$RANDOM  --privileged
Error from server (Forbidden): admission webhook "pod-security-webhook.kubernetes.io" denied the request: pods "rubelagu-32081" is forbidden: violates PodSecurity "restricted:latest": privileged (container "rubelagu-32081" must not set securityContext.privileged=true), allowPrivilegeEscalation != false (container "rubelagu-32081" must set securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation=false), unrestricted capabilities (container "rubelagu-32081" must set securityContext.capabilities.drop=["ALL"]), runAsNonRoot != true (pod or container "rubelagu-32081" must set securityContext.runAsNonRoot=true), seccompProfile (pod or container "rubelagu-32081" must set securityContext.seccompProfile.type to "RuntimeDefault" or "Localhost")
```

Note: that you get the error forbidding privileged pods even when the namespace `policy-test1` has no label `pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce`, so you know that **this rule comes from the pod-security-webhook that we just installed and configured**.

Now if you want to create a pod you will be forced to create in a way that complies with the `restricted` PSS, by specifying `runAsNonRoot`, `seccompProfile.type` and `capabilities` and For example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-1
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  securityContext:
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
    seccompProfile:
      type: RuntimeDefault
  containers:
    - name: test
      image: ecerulm/ubuntu-tools:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "--", "sleep 900"]
      securityContext:
        privileged: false
        allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
        capabilities:
          drop:
            - ALL
```